# Configuring servlet to connect to Gmail server

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to configure servlet to send a message  to Gmail, but I'm getting waiting for reply message down my browser window.

Here's the servlet code:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;


public class JavaMailServlet extends HttpServlet 
{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{

    try{

        String userName=request.getParameter("p1");
        String password=request.getParameter("p2");;

        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port",465);


        Session ses=Session.getInstance(props,null);
        Message msg=new MimeMessage(ses);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(request.getRequestURI()));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("Boyofbackstreet@gmail.com"));
        msg.setSubject("Hello");
        msg.setText("What's up?");
        Transport.send(msg);
        response.getWriter().println("Message sent");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

What do I've to do to make the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you haven't set up any authentication as far as I can tell. You've grabbed the username and the password from the request (I do hope this is over HTTPS) but you haven't used it anywhere.

I *strongly* recommend that you try to get this working in a console app which will be *much* easier to debug than a servlet, *then* put it into a servlet environment.

Comment: Good idea about putting it into a console app, not that my vote counts with your decision to do community wiki.

Comment: This time I used Authentication, but I'm still getting "waiting for reply" message. What do I've  to do now?

Comment: @RichardOD: A vote this late in the day wouldn't have made any difference to rep anyway. @JavaLearner: As I suggested before, don't experiment in a servlet to start with. See what happens in a command line app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you haven't authenticated anything.  The url you'll want to authenticate with GMail is this one.

https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=mail&Email=YOUREMAIL&Passwd=URLENCODEDPASSWORD

You'll want to substitute appropriate values for YOUREMAIL and URLENCODEDPASSWORD.  You can encode your password with a simple

```
URLEncoder.encode("password");
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've been doing this stuff with Google Voice lately and got excited about your question.  This is for HTTP stuff.  You might be able to use this.  If not, it'll be useful for someone someday ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution you need to do.
1. Instead of using Transport.send() use the following line of code

```
Transport tp = session.getTransport("smtp");
  tp.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, userName, password);
  tp.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Your Program should work then.